# pg_dump not recognized, even though I've confirmed the binary is present

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to do a dump of a table in PostgreSQL via pgAdmin3. When I try to run the the following command:

```
pg_dump -t schema.table_name database_name > chosen_save_name.sql
```

it errors out and just points to the first character.

I've gone to *File* -> *Options* -> *Binary Paths* -> *PG bin path* and verified that the pg_dump is in there (listed as pg_dump.exe).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not trying to run the pg_dump utility from the SQL query editor, are you? You probably want [this](https://www.pgadmin.org/screenshots/#12).

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, haha. Can you explain what I should be doing differently? I'm using pgAdmin3, not 4, and I'm using a desktop application, not a webapp. My program looks pretty different from yours, so I'm not sure how to get to the same screen.